# RVM - cannot install thrift on Amazon Linux checking strlcpy() in string.h

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems, rvm, thrift

I'm using:

- Amazon Linux - 2012.09
- RVM v1.19.1
- Ruby ruby-1.9.3-p362 (via RVM)
- System ruby 1.8.7
- Thrift v0.7.0 (I know there is a newer version that removes the C dependancy, however, I have a dependancy that requires v0.7.0)

I'm running the following command which happily installs gems until is crashes out at thrift:

```
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-1.9.3-p362 exec bundle install
```

which produces the error:

```
Installing thrift (0.7.0)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for strlcpy() in string.h... no
creating Makefile

make
compiling compact_protocol.c
compiling struct.c
struct.c:28:1: error: static declaration of ‘strlcpy’ follows non-static declaration
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:198:20: note: previous declaration of ‘strlcpy’ was here
make: *** [struct.o] Error 1
```

I can see quite a lot discussion around this topic, however, no real solution - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks